# Reading from a .pts file that has no header into a point cloud

Tags: matlab, import, point-clouds

I have a file with .pts ending which contains 6 columns of number. it is practically a text file since it has no defined header or anything else. A snipit for example:

```
497074.93 5419772.04 266.04 12 1 1 
497074.93 5419772.08 266.02 15 1 1 
497074.93 5419772.09 266.05 13 1 1 
497074.93 5419772.11 266.05 13 1 1 
497074.94 5419772.14 266.02 11 1 1 
497074.94 5419772.15 266.04 13 1 1 
497074.94 5419772.17 266.04 14 1 1 
497074.94 5419772.18 266.05 14 1 1
```

I have two questions here:

- Are these xyz values with RGB attached?
- How can I load them into matlab and save it as a point cloud?

The data was obtained from [this link](http://www2.isprs.org/commissions/comm3/wg4/detection-and-reconstruction.html) and as best as I can tell is supposed to contain a point cloud of some format.

Comment: Hey! Any luck figuring out what each field stands for? I have a similar data structuring pattern in the .pts sample I have at my disposal, but the supposed RGB (later three) field values are not in the range 0-255.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what concerns the reading in, you can use `textscan`:

```
filename = '*** Full path to your text file ***';
fid = fopen(filename, 'r');
if fid == -1, error('Cannot open file! Check filename or location.'); end
readdata = cell2mat(textscan(fid,'%f%f%f%f%f%f'));
fclose(fid);
```

This code will save the data in a matrix with 6 columns, if the file does not contain data other than the numbers. The format `%f` can be changed according to your needs (see https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html).

About the meaning of the data: when I click on the link I don't see any data so please be more specific on that. Besides that, why would you use data of which you don't know the meaning?

Comment: Up until now I have only managed to familiarize myself with the ply format. It is part of my learning curve.